# Angular Edge browser not work with nativeElement.scrollTo method

Tags: angular

I have an issue only with edge browser when I'm using nativeElement.scrollTo(0,0) method.
the scrollTo method is undefined.

I have div wrapper with scroll on Y axis and I have a method that should scroll to top.

#### My HTML

```
<button (click)="goUp()">Scroll UP</button>
<div class="wrapper" #wrapper>
 <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
```

## MY Component Class

```
export class AppComponent  {
 @ViewChild('wrapper') wrapperElement: ElementRef;

 goUp(){
   this.wrapperElement.nativeElement.scrollTo(0,0);
 }
}
```

[I created demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xxeguz?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: Hello. This is a Edge bug and not angular bug. See native js here https://jsfiddle.net/mnr7h97h/

Comment: Open issue in microsoft: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/8405952/

Comment: any solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be another bug reported for this: 
https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/15534521/

A workaround for `scrollTo(0,0)` would be `scrollTop = 0`

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by other answers, this is a reported bug.
Anyone else who runs into this issue can go ahead and install a polyfill.
I used [smoothscroll](https://github.com/iamdustan/smoothscroll) to solve this issue.
In my case, had no code changes.